# I'm trying to find the average of a 'score' column for all the data that has the same 'date'. I have it working with Sequelize code

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, koa

```
const data = await db.Reviews.findAll({attributes : ['reviewDate,score'[db.Reviews.sequelize.fn('AVG', 
                       db.Reviews.sequelize.col('score')), 'countdata']],
                       group : ['Reviews.reviewDate'],
                      where: { companyId: competitorId
                      },
              })
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Comment: `select review_date, avg(score) from reviews group by review_date`?

Comment: `findAll` does not have the option `group`.